# Enabling bracket colorization in Monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor

How do I enable bracket pairs colorizations in Monaco editor version 0.28.1

I'm able to create a working editor with the following code, but brackets are not colorized.

```
public createEditor(domElt: HTMLElement, value: string)
    {
        let editor = monaco.editor.create(domElt, {
            value: value,
            language: 'sql',
            lineNumbers: 'off',
            minimap: {
                enabled: false
            }
        });
        editor.getModel().updateOptions({
            bracketColorizationOptions:
            {
                enabled: true
            }
        });
        return editor;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link should help:
https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

tldr;

```
public createEditor(domElt: HTMLElement, value: string)
{
    let editor = monaco.editor.create(domElt, {
        value: value,
        language: 'sql',
        lineNumbers: 'off',
        minimap: {
            enabled: false
        },
        "bracketPairColorization.enabled": true
    });
    return editor;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).